# Java read Properties file that is in same package as the class

Tags: java

I'm stuck in this for almost an hour so please help me.

I'm using netbeans and under my `Sources Packages` I have a package called `com.cmsv1.properties`. Inside this package I have 1 java class and `.properties` file. Called `config.java` and `config.properties`.

I've tried so many solutions I got from the internet but nothing works. I always get `nullPointerException`.

The following are the solutions i've tried:

```
try
          {
              Properties prop = new Properties();
              InputStream is = config.class.getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
          }
        catch (Exception e)
          {
              System.out.println("got error");
          }
```

another is:

```
try
          {
              Properties prop = new Properties();
              InputStream input = config.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
              prop.load(input);
          }
        catch (Exception e)
          {
              System.out.println("got error");
          }
```

And a couple more solutions. Please tell me how can I do this. Remember both of my java class and .properties file are in the same package. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you try `"/com/cmsv1/properties/config.properties"` ?

Comment: Using which snippet?

Comment: tried both, does not work.

Comment: Does `InputStream in = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/com/cmsv1/properties/config.properties");` work better ?

Comment: No luck sir. My program crash in this line prop.load(in);

Comment: Try something simpler.  Create a text file: "Hello World!"  Store it in your `.jar`.  Can you retrieve that file?

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler is compiling the properties file into your jar, this should work:

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first try was almost exactly right:

```
try
{
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream is = config.class.getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("got error");
}
```

Except that you need to load and close the InputStream:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
try (InputStream is = config.class.getResourceAsStream("config.properties")) {
    prop.load(is);
}
```

Also, you need to catch *only* the exception you need to catch:

```
catch (IOException e)
```

This is because other exceptions, especially unchecked exceptions (like NullPointerException), indicate programmer errors.  You don’t catch those, you *let them make your program fail,* so you can discover and fix them.  Hiding them does not make your program work properly!

*ALWAYS* show the stack trace of a caught exception, either with a logging statement, exception chaining, or `printStackTrace()`.  If something goes wrong, you want to know why it happened and where it happened:

```
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Regarding the use of Class.getResource versus ClassLoader.getResource, you should always use Class.getResource (or Class.getResourceAsStream).  Among the reasons for this is that it will work in Java 9 modular applications.

If getResourceAsStream returns null, it’s because your properties file is not in the same location as your compiled .class file.

Comment: The advice to use Class.getResource when it's code reading its own resource is good, you should never use ClassLoader.getResource for that case. The question doesn't make it clear whether the config.properties file is in the same location as Config.class. If it's not in the same directory (on the file system or in a JAR file) then getResourceAsStream will return null. So the code fragment should check if the input stream is null.

Answer (score -2):

(Not enough reputation to comment)

Have you tried with this?

```
InputStream input = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propertiesFile);
    properties.load(input);
```

Comment: Still nullPointerException :(

Answer (score -2):

```
public Properties getPropertiesFromFile(String propertieFileName) throws IOException
    {
        try (InputStream propertyFile = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propertieFileName)
        {

            if (propertyFile == null)
            {
                //logger not found
            }
            Properties propeties = new Properties();
            propeties.load(propertyFile);
            return propeties;
        }
    }
```